# php file_put_contents("nombre.rtf",$rtf); does not show me characters like ñ,ó, í

Tags: php, special-characters, rtf

my problem is this: I'm trying to read a text in *. RTF in php to add values ​​to my database in mysql, everything goes well until I open the file that generated and I see no special characters has kept me well. Here is my code, sorry but this my first post and I don't know how to set it properly:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

<?php
ini_set("default_charset", "utf-8");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");


// Read rtf
$plantilla = file_get_contents('plantilla_titulo.rtf');


// Agregamos los escapes necesarios
$plantilla = addslashes($plantilla);
$plantilla = str_replace('\r','\\r',$plantilla);
$plantilla = str_replace('\t','\\t',$plantilla);

// Data in php to rtf
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$curso = $_POST["curso"];
$fechahoy = date("d-m-Y", time());

//Here I Replace who  shows me for special characters, 
//but it doesn't works, now show me characters like " or +- ...
$plantilla = str_replace("\'d3",'Ó',$plantilla);
$plantilla = str_replace("\'f1",'ñ',$plantilla);
$plantilla = str_replace("\'f3",'ó',$plantilla);
$plantilla = str_replace("\'ed",'í',$plantilla);
$plantilla=utf8_encode($plantilla);


// Procces rtf
eval( '$rtf = <<<EOF_RTF
' . $plantilla . '
EOF_RTF;
' );

//Here i do a var_dump($rtf); and show me special characters. 

// Save rtf
file_put_contents("$nombre-$fechahoy.rtf",$rtf);


echo "<a href=\"$nombre-$fechahoy.rtf\">download</a>";

?>

    </body>
</html>
```

I've made a manual "debug" and my problem is in that's line because I'm doing var_dump($rtf); and show it to me right ... I hope you can help me, Thank You!

Comment: You want to read in a rich-text format document ( as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format ), replace some placeholders and save the "new" document in the filesystem?

Comment: yes! that's what I want, and does it perfectly unless by special characters that contains the RTF

Comment: no one can help me??? :( :(

Answer (score 0):

First, `decode`, and then `replace`.

```
$plantilla = utf8_decode($plantilla);
$plantilla = str_replace("\'e1",'á',$plantilla);
$plantilla = str_replace("\'c1",'Á',$plantilla);
$plantilla = str_replace("\'e9",'é',$plantilla);
$plantilla = str_replace("\'c9",'É',$plantilla); 
etc...
// Save rtf, here decode again
$rtf = utf8_decode($rtf);

file_put_contents("$nombre-$fechahoy.rtf",$rtf);
```